# Create a child resource through a parent resource's index table - Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Hi I want to put a link in a index table of a resource to create a child resource.
I got a Sale, and an operation:

```
class Sale < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  has_one :operation, dependent: :destroy
end

class Operation < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :sale
end
```

And I want to be able to create an operation through an index table of sales. 
Thing is, I need it to be created on the button/link click, and not be transferred to a new operation view. (Operation has only sale_id and id as attributes)
Something like that

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Sale Id</th>
  </tr>

  <% @sales.each do |sale| %>
      <td><%= sale.id %></td>
      <td><%= link_to 'Show', sale_path(sale) %></td>
      <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_sale_path(sale) %></td>
      <td><%= link_to 'Delete', sale,
              method: :delete,
              data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
      <td> <%= form_for (@operation) do |o| %>
             <%= o.submit 'Create Operation'%> 
           <% end %> 
      </td>
    </tr>                     
  <% end %>
</table>
```

But I got this error: 'First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty'

I also tried this:

```
<td> 
  <%= fields_for :operation, @sales.operation do |o| %> 
    <%= o.submit "Create Operation" %>
  <% end %>
</td>
```

And I got this: 
undefined method `operation' for Sale::ActiveRecord_Relation:0xb1a4ece4>

tried this  as well :

```
<td> 
  <%= link_to  'Create Operation', 'operations#create' %> 
</td>
```

But it sends me to the operation index view without creating an operation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty

The error means `@operation` is `nil` in the *form*. You should define `@operation` in the `sales#index` method as the form is in `sales/index.html.erb`

```
def index
  @operation = Operation.new
end
```

> I need it to be created on the button/link click, and not be
>   transferred to a new operation view

If you meant,you shouldn't be redirected to another view after the button, then you have to use *AJAX*. I recommend you see these [*Guides*](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html) to understand how to do with *AJAX*